# Popoulate dropdown (select ) using AJAX and ORACLE and JSP without using php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oracle, jsp

I need to retrieve the options of a drop down menu dynamically but without using a php script . Using only jsp/jquery/ajax and data base connection I need to auto populate the options depending on the value selected in first drop down menu.

The below html page has two select dropdowns in which on selecting brand we need to autopopulate the id .

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>PHP MySQL Insert Tutorial</title>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <select id='brand'>
 <option value='nokia'>nokia</option>
 <option value='motorola'>motorola</option>
 <option value='samsung'>samsung</option>
 </select>

 <select id='item'>

 </select>

 <script src='fetch.js'></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Below is the java script which is taking a php file as a input for db connection

```
  $.getJSON(
     'fetch.php',
     'brand='+$('#brand').val(),
     function(result){
     $('#item').empty();
     $.each(result.result, function(){
     $('#item').append('<option>'+this['item']+'</option>');
     });
     }
     );
    });
```

Below is the php script

```
    <?php
     define('HOST','localhost');
     define('USERNAME', 'root');
     define('PASSWORD','');
     define('DB','myDatabase');

     $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB);

     $brand = $_GET['brand'];

     $sql = "select item from products where brand='$brand'";

     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

     $result = array();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
     array_push($result, 
     array('item'=>$row[0]));
     }

     echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

     mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

I need to use a Oracle database for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use servlet instead of JSP. In the method `doGet()` of the servlet write the following:

```
...
String brand = request.getParameter("brand");
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

// here access to the DAO layer and retrieve the information

String json = new Gson().toJson(items);
response.setContentType("application/json");

response.getWriter().write(json);
...
```

In your JavaScript code, track changes in the first combobox and accordingly change the content of the second combobox:

```
...
$('#brand').change(function(event) {

        var brand = $("select#brand").val();

        $.post('YourServletHere', {
                brand: brand
        }, function(response) {
              var item = $('#item');
              item.empty();
              $.each(response, function(idx, value) {
                 $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(item);
              });
        });
    });
});
...
```